# Contador para inserir linha em branco a cada 5 células iguais

Tags: microsoft-excel, visual-basic-6, excel-vba

Olá, estou tentando fazer uma macro pra um botão, que coloca uma linha em branco a cada 5 células com conteúdo igual, porém sou bastante leigo na sintaxe de VB e não tenho certeza se a lógica está correta também, exemplo do que deve acontecer:

```
ADA
ADA
ADA
ADA
ADA

ADA
```

Meu código atual é esse:

```
Private Sub Divide5_Click()
Dim Lst As Long
Dim n As Long
Dim i As Integer
Lst = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(x1Up).Row
i = 0
For n = 2 To Lst Step 1
  With Range("A" & n)
    If .Value = .Offset(1).Value Then
     i = i + 1
    End If
    If i = 5 Then
     .EntireRow.Insert
    End If
  End With
Next n
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está perto, fiz algumas modificações para conseguir as interações que você quer:

```
Sub Divide5_Click()
Dim Lst As Long
Dim n As Long
Dim i As Integer

Lst = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
i = 0
n = 2
Do While n <= Lst 'For não itera dinamicamente
    With Range("A" & n)
        If .Value = .Offset(-1).Value Then
            i = i + 1
            If i = 4 Then
                .Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
                i = 0 'Reinicie o contador após inserir linha
                Lst = Lst + 1 'limite dinâmico
            End If
        Else
            i = 0 'Reinicie o contador se a célula mudar de valor e não completar 5
        End If
    End With
    n = n + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Tu também tá muito perto, haha, a primeira está com 6, o restante funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: hahaha meu erro, eu pensei que a primeira célula era o nome do campo e você não tem que iterar isso. Eu já corrijo a resposta.

Comment: A ideia não é ruim, caso eu tenha cabeçalho certamente utilizaria isso, mas esse plano apenas recebe dados pra alimentar pesquisas de outros planos.